# Active portfolio management - characteristic portfolios derivation

Tags: portfolio-optimization, portfolio, modern-portfolio-theory

In the book *Active Portfolio Management* by Grinold and Kahn, on page 30, when it derives the characteristic portfolio $h_a$ for some characteristic vector $a$, the problem is set up as
$$\min h^TVh$$
s.t. $h^ta=1$

Why do we not need to add the constraint that $1^Th=1$ ($h$ should be a weight vector of a portfolio) here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below **proposition 1** (In the 2nd edition at *p. 28*?), at the beginning of the chapter, he specifically writes:

> Characteristic portfolios are not necessarily fully invested. They can include long and short positions and have significant leverage. Take the characteristic portfolio for earnings-to-price ratios. Since typical earnings-to-price ratios range roughly from 0.15 to 0, the characteristic portfolio will require leverage to generate a portfolio earnings-to-price ratio of 1. $[\ldots]$

In essence, he argues there is no need for the full investment constraint, hence $1^Th =1$ is excluded.